# Is there a way to make a given value relative to another piece of value?

Tags: workflow

I'm trying to animate several objects along a curve with the Follow Path constraint. If I adjust the Offset of one object, I must adjust all the ones behind it. This is tedious. Is there a way for me make the Offsets relative to one another?
For example,  is equal to (  + 10). If Suzanne has an offset of 24, then cube's offset is 34, ect.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that easily with [drivers](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Basics/Drivers). Drivers can be hard to understand, but are very powerful.

1. <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> click on the *Offset* field in the *Follow Path* constraint that you want to be linked to the other constraint's value (I will call this *object 1*).
2. Chose *Add driver*
3. Open up the *Graph Editor* and switch it to *Drivers*, click on the *Offset Factor (Follow Path)* in the list of drivers on the left.
4. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open up the *Properties* panel to edit the driver. [image: Graph Editor showing drivers]
5. Change the var type to *Single Property*, point the *Prop:* to the object that has the other *Follow Path* constraint.
6. Select the object that has the other *Follow Path* constraint (in my example it is *Suzanne*).
7. <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> click on the *Offset* field in the *Follow Path* constraint chose *Copy Data Path*
8. Select *object 1*, go back to the *Graph Editor*, and paste in the value for the *Path:*, should be this `constraints["Follow Path"].offset_factor`.
9. Change the *Expr:* to be `var + 10`.